# hyperledger fabric ubuntu command "make configtxgen cryptogen" error 1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

while running "make cryptogen configtxgen " command in ubuntu am getting below error ...... Need your help Team ☺

> can't load package: package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" in any of:
>   /usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOROOT)
>   /home/mallikarjuna/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOPATH)
>   find: ‘/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim’: No such file or directory
>   .build/bin/configtxgen
>   CGO_CFLAGS=" " GOBIN=/home/mallikarjuna/fabric/.build/bin go install -tags "" -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/metadata.CommitSHA=abe9d79" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen
>   can't load package: package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen" in any of:
>   /usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen (from $GOROOT)
>   /home/mallikarjuna/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen (from $GOPATH)
>   Makefile:258: recipe for target '.build/bin/configtxgen' failed
>   make: *** [.build/bin/configtxgen] Error 1

Comment: looks like GOPATH error, please make sure to set it as recommended.

Comment: yes i got it  @adnan.c GOPATH is not set